# Creating 3D image from HGT files?

Tags: dem, software-recommendations, 3d, terrain

Is there any command line tool to create a 3D terrain from a DEM SRTM HGT file like this?

I mean, given a camera position, a HGT file and a satelite image.

[image]

**EDIT 1**

First try to adapt `mdsumner`'s answer:
This is the full code:

First, install all I need (Docker image from R-Base):

```
apt-get update & apt-get install -y libproj-dev xorg libx11-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libfreetype6-dev libgdal-dev --fix-missing
```

Install required packages:

```
install.packages(c("proj4"))
install.packages(c("reproj"))
install.packages(c("remotes", "quadmesh", "rgl"))
install.packages(c("raster"))
install.packages(c("rgdal"))
```

Load the SRTM DEM HGT file:

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
dem <- raster("/home/docker/S14W042.hgt")
```

Load a texture image and execute. My image is just a PNG file (must be a sub product of the HGT file - anything that I can extract using GDAL - or an ordinary image):

```
im <- brick("/home/docker/S14W042.map.png" )
qm <- quadmesh::quadmesh(dem, texture = im)
```

Error:

```
Error in quadmesh.BasicRaster(dem, texture = im) :
  texture must be a 3-layer raster with RGB values (in 0-255)
```

Please help here. `NOTE:` I can't `auto-download` anything. All files MUST be here when creating the image.

**EDIT 2**

I realized that I can use any X,Y,Z map server instead MapBox to get the imagery, including my own server.

```
First I try with ArcGIS online:

Give any API-KEY. Don't care.
Sys.setenv(MAPBOX_API_KEY="fdfsdfsdfsdfsdf")

u <- "https://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{zoom}/{y}/{x}"

im <- cc_location(cbind(147, -42), base_url = u)

Done.
```

Comment: This 3D terrain was created with photoshop plugin 3d terrain.

Comment: Ok but I don't want to say exactly THIS image. I mean an image LIKE this. Photoshop IS NOT a command line tool.

Comment: I expect it's a one layer palette image but you need a  3-layer raster with RGB values (in 0-255) so try im_rgb <- setValues(brick(im[[1]], im[[1]], im[[1]]), t(col2rgb(im@legend@colortable)))  - but I'm guessing, does your im@legend@colortable have a set of hex code colours?

Comment: I don't know. I'm completely blind because I don't now anything about R and raster files. I'm just a Java developer. But I will follow anything you tell me to do. Basicaly I have just a HGT file. I can use GDAL tools to extract slope as TIF, an image as PNG, some kind of colored image using ramp color and so on. I don't have any way to download anything at execution time because production environment limitations. I can use my Geoserver to get any map image I need in a given BBOX but it is limited to the layers I have. I think the texture may not be exactly a satelite image.

Comment: Ah whoops, you need  im_rgb <- setValues(brick(im[[1]], im[[1]], im[[1]]), t(col2rgb(im@legend@colortable[ values(im) + 1])))  - I'm just putting this into quadmesh now so we don't have to think about it

Comment: In what part of my code above I need to inject this piece of code? Must I replace `qm <- quadmesh::quadmesh(dem, texture = im)` to `qm <- quadmesh::quadmesh(dem, texture = im_rgb)` ? Please slow a little down. Remember I'm a newbie.

Comment: I'm sympathetic, this side of things is totally opaque - and there's really nothing about this anywhere and unlikely to come - but I upgraded quadmesh just now so if you can stand installing another package from github ...

Comment: Yes, to the code q - but do also consider that I can't run your code so I can't  be totally sure, and this isn't a great forum for sharing reproducible examples.

Comment: Hum... ok. No need for hurries. I'll try this and come back if any trouble.

Comment: By the way, how can I get this modification you made in `quadmesh`?

Comment: `rgl::shade3d(qm, lit = FALSE)` Gave me `rgl.init(initValue, onlyNULL) : RGL: unable to open X11 display`

Comment: Uh, sorry - the mod in quadmesh is available with remotes::install_github("hypertidy/quadmesh"), the rgl stuff means you aren't getting a suitable graphics device - either do it on a machine that can spawn rgl graphics (try rgl::plot3d(1, 1, 1) as a minimum) or run rgl::rglwidget() which might work

Comment: btw, this is a very unsuitable venue for discussions, feel free to take it to the dev repo Issues: https://github.com/hypertidy/quadmesh/issues

Comment: Please add all these considerations to your answer to make it richer. I'm in a headless environment so I don't have any display (in the future it will be automatized in a service and don't even have a terminal). Please modify your answer to fit it in these needs (`command line tool` implies in `no gui` I think). I'll stop this conversation now to avoid long comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with R, visualized with the rgl package, and converting the DEM and image to `mesh3d` form with the `quadmesh` package.

Here I use another package `ceramic` from github to obtain the DEM and image, but you can replace those by reading the DEM with `raster::raster()` and the image with `raster::brick()`.

```
## install.packages(c("remotes", "quadmesh", "rgl))
## remotes::install_github("hypertidy/ceramic")
library(ceramic)
dem <- cc_elevation(cbind(120.9647, -8.8033), buffer = 15000)
im <- cc_location(dem, type = "mapbox.satellite")
qm <- quadmesh::quadmesh(dem, texture = im)

rgl::shade3d(qm, lit = FALSE);
```

Use the `rgl` function `view3d()` to control the view, or interact with the scene to put it where you need.

[image]

Comment: Please see my `EDIT 1`